# Truffle error missmatch artifact

Tags: truffle, ganache

What does this means?network/artifact mismatch Contract has not been deployed to detected network but when i write truffle network i can see mine.

Answer (score 0):

An artifact is a json file inside the `build/` directory that contains information of the contract's deployment. For example address, network id and libraries linked.

The mismatch error appear when the information in the artifacts doesn't match the current network.

- Sometimes it happens because the network id has changed. For example ganache by default will use a different id every time.
- Other by a Truffle bug that stores an invalid network id in the artifact.

Comment: i ffound it dapper was the issue

Comment: @PanosKor Please, add as an answer how you solved your issue so it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Well i had an extesion called Dapper..so i unistall it and it;s ok now!